# How do I sort a 2 dimensional array columns in Swift based on the values in a row?

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

How can I sort a two dimensional array based on values in one of the rows?

```
let array = [["X", "Y",   1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
             ["V", "W", "A","B","C","D","E"]
]

let sorted = [["X", "Y",   5,  4,  3,  2,  1],
              ["V", "W", "E","D","C","B","A"]
    ]
```

The Swift `Array.sort({e1, e2 in e1 < e2})` passes in row elements, not column elements.

To make matters worse the first two column in the row must not be sorted.

Bear in mind row 2 must be rearranged according to the row 1 order.  So assuming we are sorting by row 0 and ignoring 1st 2 columns

```
[["X", "Y",   1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
 ["V", "W", "E","B","A","D","F"]]
```

should become

```
[["X", "Y",   5,  4,  3,  2,  1],
 ["V", "W", "F","D","A","B","E"]]
```

Comment: Didn't understand the logic you want to use to get the sorted array. Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

First map the array elements and split first 2 elements from the sub array to skip sorting. Now sort the remaining elements using switch pattern matching. Then join the sorted array with first 2 elements.

```
let array = [["X", "Y",   1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
             ["V", "W", "A","B","C","D","E"]]

let sorted = array.map { $0[..<2] + $0[2...].sorted(by: {
    switch ($0,$1) {
    case (let a as Int, let b as Int): return a > b
    case (let a as String, let b as String): return a > b
    case (let a as Date, let b as Date): return a > b
    case (_, _): return false
    }
})}.map { Array($0) }
print(sorted)
```

> [["X", "Y", 5, 4, 3, 2, 1], ["V", "W", "E", "D", "C", "B", "A"]]

Comment: wow - I'll test that in a playground.  Bear in mind row 2 must be rearranged according to the row 1 order.  So
[["X", "Y",   1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
 ["V", "W", "E","B","A","D","F"]]

should become

[["X", "Y",   5,  4,  3,  2,  1],
 ["V", "W", "F","D","A","B","E"]]

Comment: @DuncanGroenewald No. Now the second array is sorted individually. I'll update the answer

Comment: I found that I have to create a new structure with the sort row data and indexes, then sort the array of this structure and then use the subsequent sorted array to find the index of the columns that has to be moved to the new position.  No doubt there is an easier way.

Comment: @DuncanGroenewald Yes. Using a struct it is easier

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I came up with - very ugly !!

```
extension Array where Element == Array<String> {
    /// Creates a totals row at the bottom
    /// ignore - number of columns to ignore at the start
    mutating func addTotalsRow(ignore: Int){
        // Create a totals row (top row)
        var totals = [String]()
        // Add columns if required
        if ignore > 0 {
            totals.append("Total")
            totals.append(contentsOf: repeatElement("", count: ignore - 1))

        }


        for row in self {
            for i in ignore..<row.count {

                let value = row[i].toDouble ?? 0.0
                if (i+1) > totals.count {
                    totals.append("0.0")
                }
                totals[i] = ((totals[i].toDouble ?? 0.0) + value).formatted4
            }
        }

        self.append(totals)

        return
    }

    /// Sort columnwise using values in 'row', ignoring first 'ignore' columns
    /// Also sorts the optional header row
    /// Returns (sortedRows, sortedHeaderRow)
    func columnSorted(_ sortRow: Int, ignoreColumnCount: Int, order: SortOrder = .ascending, headerRow: [String]?)->([[String]], [String]?) {

        // Now calculate a totals row
        var newHeader: [String]?

        // Create an array of objects holding the total and the column index
        var indexes = [IX]()

        let totals = self[sortRow]

        // Ignore the text columns
        for i in ignoreColumnCount..<totals.count {
            indexes.append(IX(total: totals[i], index: i))
        }
        // Sort IX by the totals
        indexes.sort(by: {ix1, ix2 in
            return order == .descending ? ix1.intTotal > ix2.intTotal : ix1.intTotal < ix2.intTotal})

        // Create the Totals data row
        var totalsRow = [String]()
        totalsRow.append(contentsOf: totals[0..<ignoreColumnCount])
        totalsRow.append(contentsOf: indexes.map({$0.total}))



        if let header = headerRow {
            newHeader = [String]()
            newHeader!.append(contentsOf: header[0..<ignoreColumnCount])
            for i in 0..<indexes.count {
                let ix = indexes[i].index
                if ((i+ignoreColumnCount)+1) > newHeader!.count {
                    newHeader!.append("")
                }
                newHeader![i+ignoreColumnCount] = header[ix]
            }
        }

        var newData = [[String]]()
        // newData.append(totalsRow)
        // Now do the same for all the rows in data
        for row in self {
            var newRow = [String]()
            newRow.append(contentsOf: row[0..<ignoreColumnCount])

            for i in 0..<indexes.count {
                let ix = indexes[i].index
                if ((i+ignoreColumnCount)+1) > newRow.count {
                    newRow.append("0.0")
                }
                newRow[i+ignoreColumnCount] = row[ix]
            }
            newData.append(newRow)
        }

        // Sort by count
        return (newData, newHeader)
    }
    /// Sort by column index 0...
    mutating func sort(by column: Int, order: SortOrder = .ascending) {

        guard column > 0 else {
            return
        }
        let index = column - 1

        self.sort(by: {r1, r2 in
            let count1 = (r1[index].toDouble ?? 0.0)
            let count2 = (r2[index].toDouble ?? 0.0)
            if let val = r1[index].toDouble {
                return order == .descending ? (r1[index].toDouble ?? 0.0) > (r2[index].toDouble ?? 0.0) : (r1[index].toDouble ?? 0.0) < (r2[index].toDouble ?? 0.0)
            } else {
                return order == .descending ? r1[index] > r2[index] : r1[index] > r2[index]
            }
        })
    }

    func sorted(by column: Int, order: SortOrder = .ascending, ignoreFirstRow: Bool = false)->[[String]] {

        guard column > 0 else {
            return self
        }
        let index = column - 1

        var resultSet = [[String]]()

        if ignoreFirstRow {
            // Save the first row
            let firstRow = self[0]

            let dataRows = self[1..<count].sorted(by: {r1, r2 in

                if let val = r1[index].toDouble {
                    return order == .descending ? (r1[index].toDouble ?? 0.0) > (r2[index].toDouble ?? 0.0) : (r1[index].toDouble ?? 0.0) < (r2[index].toDouble ?? 0.0)
                } else {
                    return order == .descending ? r1[index] > r2[index] : r1[index] < r2[index]
                }

            })
            resultSet.append(firstRow)
            resultSet.append(contentsOf: dataRows)
        } else {

            let dataRows = self[0..<count].sorted(by: {r1, r2 in

                if let val = r1[index].toDouble {
                    return order == .descending ? (r1[index].toDouble ?? 0.0) > (r2[index].toDouble ?? 0.0) : (r1[index].toDouble ?? 0.0) < (r2[index].toDouble ?? 0.0)
                } else {
                    return order == .descending ? r1[index] > r2[index] : r1[index] < r2[index]
                }

            })
            resultSet.append(contentsOf: dataRows)
        }

        return resultSet
    }
    func printArray(){
        for row in self {
            print("\(row)")
        }
    }
}
```